# How to use LineProcessor when checked exceptions occur?

Tags: guava

I'm inserting the lines of a file into a database using plain JDBC. For that, I'm using Guava's [`LineProcessor`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html), along with [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html). However that interface can only throw an `IOException` with its method `processLine(String)`.

This doesn't feel right when an `SQLException` is thrown. So far I wrap the `SQLException` in an unchecked exception, but I'm wondering if I should not wrap it in an `IOException` as the interface doesn't mention anything about another exception. Simply return false? This seems more wrong than anything.

Technically, I think it was an oversight from Guava's team not to explicitly mention what behavior is expected when a checked exception occurs whether in the wiki or the Javadoc.

So how should I actually use `LineProcessor` when I'm encountering checked exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `SQLException` into an `IOException` is a valid solution, because you are reading from a file (input) and writing to a database (output). The root cause of the `IOException` would be the `SQLException`.

You are correct though on the documentation, since it only mentions that the `LineProcessor` is meant to be used with the `readLines` methods. It doesn't explicitly say what behaviour is expected when an exception occurs. The documentation of `readLines`, however, mentions that an `IOException` should be thrown when an I/O error occurs.

Note that the `LineProcessor` is also designed to be able to *collect* a result and return it using the `LineProcessor#getResult` method, so you can always fully read the file first and return a result (if your files aren't too big). This will allow you to split the responsibilities of reading/processing the lines and the insertion of the data in your database.

Comment: I should not have mentioned `Closer`, it confuses. Also, I mentioned that I wrap it (using `Throwables#propage(Throwable)` even). And you're giving a technical solution where I ask more about a best practice (see my second paragraph, plus the usage of "should"). If you would reformulate to focus on the best practice, I'd gladly upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Edited. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that all callback-based APIs have with checked exceptions. You can make the callback able to throw any type of `Exception`, but then the methods that use the callback also have to throw `Exception`, which is a pain to users (especially if the actual callback doesn't throw any exception at all!). You can also parameterize the callback with a type of checked exception (e.g. `LineProcessor<T, X extends Throwable>`) and make the method on it able to throw an `X`, but what if there are two or three types of checked exceptions it could throw? It's just a mess.

In this case, `IOException` is allowed because A) it's the most likely type of exception most callbacks would have a need to throw, and B) (more importantly) the methods that use `LineProcessor` (e.g. `CharStreams.readLines(Readable, LineProcessor<T>)` already necessarily have to be able to throw `IOException` since they do I/O, so it's no extra burden on the user if the `LineProcessor` can also throw `IOException`.

The easiest way to handle this might simply be to create an `UncheckedSQLException` class whose cause must be a `SQLException`, and then throw that from your `LineProcessor` and catch it and unwrap it wherever you use that `LineProcessor`.